# How to convert varchar to datetime for any format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

Suppose I have created a table and insert data as below

```
create table datetimefromat
(
     SlNo int identity,
     datetimeVarchar varchar(100)
)
go

DECLARE @now datetime

SET @now = GETDATE()

insert into datetimefromat (datetimeVarchar)  
values (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 0)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 1)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 3)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 5)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 20)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 13)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 22)),
       (convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 111));
go

select * from datetimefromat
go

+------+--------------------------+
| SlNo |     datetimeVarchar      |
+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | Mar 29 2016 12:46PM      |
|    2 | 03/29/16                 |
|    3 | 29/03/16                 |
|    4 | 29-03-16                 |
|    5 | 2016-03-29 12:46:32      |
|    6 | 29 Mar 2016 12:46:32:087 |
|    7 | 03/29/16 12:46:32 PM     |
|    8 | 2016/03/29               |
+------+--------------------------+
```

I want to convert it back to normal datetime

```
select 
    *,
    CONVERT(datetime, datetimeVarchar) 
from datetimefromat
```

But this causes an error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 11
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How can I fix this?

Because I want to update the existing records and change the `varchar` column to `datetime`

Comment: "How can I fix this " - don't store date as string in first place?

Comment: Records 2 and 3 are stored in 'dd/mm/yy' and 'mm/dd/yy' format respectively. Assuming you had run this query on the 4th of March, they would be stored as '04/03/16' and '03/04/16'. There is no way for a computer to work out whether this is 3rd March or 4th April. In fact, there's no way for a human to know it...!

Comment: Supposing you have no control over the db (otherwise, don't store dates as strings, like Mitch said), it's impossible to correct these dates. What date would `03-04-2016` represent? 3rd of april or 4th of march? If you can't tell, how are you going to tell sql-server to interpret this?

Comment: You can use the style when you convert back to datetime, example  CONVERT(datetime, yourDateColumn, 112)  but if you have more rows with different styles than I join to the commentators above that you should use datetime datatype to store a date.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Firstly, you need to specify the style when converting back to datetime. Secondly, 22 is not a valid style.

This code works:

```
CREATE TABLE datetimeformat
    (SlNo INT IDENTITY,
    datetimeVarchar VARCHAR(100),
    datetimeFormat INT);
GO

DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE();

INSERT INTO
    datetimeformat (datetimeVarchar, datetimeFormat)
VALUES
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 0), 0),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 1), 1),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 3), 3),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 5), 5),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 20), 20),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 13), 13),
--  (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 22), 22),
    (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @now, 111), 111);
GO

SELECT
    *,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, datetimeVarchar, datetimeFormat)
FROM
    datetimeformat;
GO
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms187928.aspx) documentation lists the possible styles.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query, this may be help you

```
select CAST((CASE WHEN isdate(datetimeVarchar) = 1 THEN datetimeVarchar 
    ELSE SUBSTRING(datetimeVarchar,4,3)+LEFT(datetimeVarchar,3)+RIGHT(datetimeVarchar,2)
    END) AS DATETIME)
from datetimefromat
```

You can use the function `isdate` to check the given value is a valid date or not, and based on the result flag you can build your own logic (ie the else part).

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISDATE(datetimeVarchar) = 1 THEN CAST(datetimeVarchar AS DATETIME) 
        ELSE [*Use logic to convert/skip other string values here*] END )
from datetimefromat
```